# Eclipse steps through comments on undo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4

When I undo a sequence of steps in a Java editor in Eclipse 3.4.2, the cursor skips over a bunch of comments unrelated to any change - only the method comments (eg. `/**`), not inline comments.

Does this happen to anyone else? Any solutions to stop it?

Comment: Do you have any automated source formatting enabled? Perhaps it's performing a formatting step (on file save, for e.g.) and your undo list then contains those automated formatting steps.

Comment: There's no save step between the undo's. 

I type some code, type some more, undo (jumps to a comment), undo (un-does code), undo (jumps to a comment), undo (un-does more code). Odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't happen on Eclipse 3.6 so accepting this to close it

Answer (score 1):

stop editing your source code while debugging ;)

Comment: oh, sorry.
I'm using eclipse 3.3.2 and my editors started showing occasional flakey behaviour, too. I learned to stop editing these files the hard way, because once that happens any further changes will only set actual code and displayed code further apart. Just close the editor and open it again.